# Dark Souls retail version to Steam?

Tags: dark-souls, version-differences

Is it possible, to register Dark Souls **CD key from retail version (Box)** on Steam (I don't want just add it to steam library but to account as other steam games)? Box version is really nice, so I'm gonna buy it, but I cannot find info about registering **CD Key**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in august 2012 a post has been made by a namco representative saying that it is indeed possible to activate the retail version on steam: 
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2901670

> Just confirmed: retail version of Dark souls Prepare to Die edition can now be authenticated in Steam and so be visible in your game library.

Answer (score 0):

It won't do the clever things steam does such as updating for you, but it will show your friends what you are playing if you add the shortcut to steam as a non-steam game.

Short version: Yes.

Comment: What I exactly wanted to know, is it possible to add box version to steam (type CD key on steam platform), but not as shortcut, just normal game as it would be bought from steam - and make all auto-updates etc. I assume it's not possible ?